# Characters at the start of xml file

Tags: php, xml, encoding, laravel-5

```
´╗┐<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

How can I strip the '´╗┐' from the above string in php? I get it when I use file_get_content($file) or laravel's File::get($file) does appear on opening the file in various text editor with all special characters showing.

Comment: Use `substr($data, strpos($data, "<"));` to remove characters before starting tag.  -----E.g.  $data is your string....

Comment: You require to remove all special char OR this one. You can try [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) for this single one.

Comment: Thanks @Ali that solves my issue. Add as an Answer and I'll mark it as accepted

Comment: @AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd str_replace didn't work couldn't match the charaters

Comment: @m1kfb: it should work if you pass utf8 decoded value into str_replace. BTW Thanks.

Comment: Seems like a BOM (Byte Order Mark).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this work using `preg_match` like this

```
$XML = '´╗┐<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';

preg_match("/<\?xml.*/", $XML, $matchs);
$newXML = $matchs[0];
```

Test it in **[Demo](https://ideone.com/a1a2zZ)**